# Trying to create a date calculation in Sharepoint Workflow

Tags: workflow

I am trying to create a Data calculation to add 1 year to the Approved on (date field) and set this as the Sunset Date.

My current workflow looks like this:

```
If Status equals Approved
   and Custom Sunset equals No
Add 1 years to ComplianceReveiw:Approved On (Output to Variable: SunsetDate)
   Then Set Variable: SunsetDate to ComplianceReview:Sunset Date
```

I know that the workflow works as I tested it a few times and set a field to change to a certain value and that does change.
I have tried to set a comment field to the Variable and it returns Blank.
I set the Comment field to the Approved On field and it does return a value of Day:Month:Year 12:00 AM
Even though the field in sharepoint is set to Data Only.....

Anyone have any idea on this?

Thanks,

Comment: I was re-reading this and i realize i mis-typed in there.
it should read
If Status equals Approved
   and Custom Sunset equals No
Add 1 years to ComplianceReveiw:Approved On (Output to Variable: SunsetDate)
   Then Set ComplianceReview:Sunset Date to Variable: SunsetDat

Was just a typo on my end, I have it setup correctly in the workflow just typed it wrong up there.

Comment: I actually think I found the resolution. It seems that the workflow will not update a "null" field, at least in this scenario. The Sunset Date was null, would not update. I put in anydate and it works flawlessly.